# Decoding Kubernetes secret

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I inherited a Kubernetes/Docker setup, and I accidentally crashed the pod by changing something relating to the DB password.

I am trying to troubleshoot this.

I don't have much Kubernetes or Docker experience, so I'm still learning how to do things.

The value is contained inside the db-user-pass credential I believe, which is an Opaque type secret.

I'm describing it:

```
kubectl describe secrets/db-user-pass
Name:         db-user-pass
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
password:  16 bytes
username:  13 bytes
```

but I have no clue how to get any data from this secret. The example on the Kubernetes site seems to assume I'll have a base64 encoded string, but I can't even seem to get that. How do I get the value for this?

Comment: Try `kubectl get secret db-user-pass -o yaml`, which will dump it out in YAML form and usually includes the encoded secret values.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. If you want to write this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: `kubectl get secret db-user-pass -o json | jq '.data | map_values(@base64d)'`. This givest the nicest results but needs the [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) dependency.

Comment: for dots in json see this: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23386

Comment: kubectl get secrets --namespace=jhalokia my-jalokia-credentials -ojsonpath='{.data.password}' | base64 -d

Answer (score 237, accepted):

You can use `kubectl get secrets/db-user-pass -o yaml` or `-o json` where you'll see the base64-encoded `username` and `password`.  You can then copy the value and decode it with something like `echo <ENCODED_VALUE> | base64 -D` (Mac OS X).

A more compact one-liner for this:

```sh
kubectl get secrets/db-user-pass --template={{.data.password}} | base64 -D
```

and likewise for the username:

```sh
kubectl get secrets/db-user-pass --template={{.data.username}} | base64 -D
```

Note: on GNU/Linux, the base64 flag is `-d`, not `-D`.

Comment: according to base64 on centos7 the command is `base64 -d` not -D

Comment: -D is not available for ubuntu 18 as well

Comment: This answer was posted by someone on a mac OS.  `-d` is the appropriate argument for decode in linux.

Comment: This template doesn't work when a key inside a secret contains a dot (e.g. `credentials.json`). The working variant is: `kubectl get secrets/secret-name --template="{{index .data \"credentials.json\" | base64decode}}"`. Also note the usage of Go's `base64decode` instead of OS's `base64` to make it work under any OS.

Comment: There is no point making this work on any OS, as docker only really works in Linux. I've updated the answer to work with bash and made a note about OS/X and zsh.

Answer (score 131):

I would suggest using this handy command. It utilizes a power of [go-templates](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/). It iterates over all values, decodes them, and prints them along with the key. It also handles not set values.

```sh
kubectl get secret name-of-secret -o go-template='
{{range $k,$v := .data}}{{printf "%s: " $k}}{{if not $v}}{{$v}}{{else}}{{$v | base64decode}}{{end}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}'

## In your case it would output
# password: decoded_password
# username: decoded_username
```

If you don't like go-templates you can use different output formats e.g. `yaml` or `json`, but that will output secrets encoded by base64.

Comment: This is the most robust answer.

Comment: Has anyone figured out the syntax to get this to work in PowerShell?  If I put the template in a file, and use `--go-template-file` it works.  But `--go-template` behaves differently (gives various errors about unexpected this or that).  Even with properly escaping the string (which, frankly, is painful).

Comment: Use: 
`kubectl get secret name-of-secret -o go-template='{{range $k,$v := .data}}{{printf \"%s: \" $k}}{{if not $v}}{{$v}}{{else}}{{$v | base64decode}}{{end}}{{\"\n\"}}{{end}}'` 
Note the escaped double quotes.

Comment: @BrettJ I recommend to use at least Powershell 7.3, since the [quoting issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1995) was [fixed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/experimental-features?view=powershell-7.3#psnativecommandargumentpassing) there. I was able to just use the command in the answer as it is.

Answer (score 114):

If you have jq (json query) this works:

```
kubectl get secret db-user-pass -o json | jq '.data | map_values(@base64d)'
```

**NOTE:**

- `db-user-pass` is the name of the k8s secret
- `.data` is the variable within that contains the secret value

Comment: This works! Note it requires jq 1.6 or higher (which is not installed baseline on some systems) and may have issues per https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/47

Comment: This gives the nicest result!

Comment: Thanks for this nice command line, the result is magic

Answer (score 30):

This should work on all platforms, with kubectl 1.11+

```
kubectl get secrets/db-user-pass --template='{{.data.password | base64decode}}'
```

If there is a "-" in the password, the following will work

```
kubectl get secrets/db-user-pass --template='{{ index .data "sql-password" | base64decode}}'
```

And if you want to get all keys, values

```
kubectl get secrets/db-user-pass --template='{{ range $key, $value := .data }}{{ printf "%s: %s\n" $key ($value | base64decode) }}{{ end }}'
```

Comment: and if there is a dash "-" in the password key the first example will not work, it will return an error: error parsing template {{ .data.sql-password |base64decode }}, template: output:1: bad character U+002D '-'   , you can do the following `kubectl get secrets/db-user-pass --template='{{ index .data "sql-password" | base64decode}}'`

Comment: Pity that https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configmap-secret/managing-secret-using-kubectl/#decoding-secret has not been updated with this more portable idiom. BTW you can include `{{"\n"}}` at the end to get a trailing newline, nicer for interactive use.

Comment: @JesseGlick thank you for clearing this point, I'll add it to the answer

Comment: This is the best answer as it does not depend on any external tool and allow you to list all the keys if you want.

Answer (score 16):

This [jsonpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/) variation works for me on OSX.

```
kubectl get secrets/db-user-pass -o jsonpath="{.data.username}" | base64 -d
```

To get secret with dot in the name.

```
kubectl get secrets/tls -o jsonpath="{.data['tls\.crt']}" | base64 -d
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 15):

If your secret keys contain dash (`-`) or dot (`.`):

```
kubectl get secret db-user-pass -o=go-template='{{index .data "password"}}' | base64 -d
```

Comment: As our `argocd-cluster` secret has a dot with `admin.password` inside it's `data`, this approach using a `go-template` was the only solution that worked for us. Here's our command: `kubectl -n argocd get secret argocd-cluster -o=go-template='{{index .data "admin.password"}}' | base64 -d; echo`.

Answer (score 11):

This is the [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#creating-a-secret-manually) you might be looking for.

Kubernetes secrets need the secrets to be given in base64 encoded format, which can be created using base64 binary in case of linux distributions.

Example:

```sh
echo "hello" | base64
aGVsbG8K
```

Kubernetes decodes the base64 encoding when we pass the secret key as environment variable or mounted as volume.

Comment: Append `--decode` parameter to decode the secret from base64.

Comment: `echo "aGVsbG8K" | base64 --decode` will output `hello`

Answer (score 10):

First, get the secret from the etcd by querying the api server using kubectl.

```
kubectl get secret db-user-pass -o yaml
```

This will give you the base64 encoded secret in yaml format.

Once you have the yaml file decode them using

> "base64 --decode"

Final command will look like this:
Don't forget the `-n` flag in echo command

`echo -n "jdddjdkkdkdmdl" | base64 --decode`

Answer (score 3):

For easier decoding you can use a tool like [ksd](https://github.com/mfuentesg/ksd) that will do the base64 decoding for you

```
kubectl get secrets/db-user-pass -o yaml | ksd
```

or using https://github.com/elsesiy/kubectl-view-secret

```
kubectl view-secret secrets/db-user-pass
```

Comment: I love this plugin, and recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

on ubuntu 18+

```
kubectl get secrets/db-user-pass --template={{.data.password}} | base64 -d
```

Comment: Does not work for me. In version 1.18.5 I get "<no value>"  when using `--template={{.data.password}}` as a parameter.

Comment: I use the same everyday, I have different clusters of version 1,17, 1.18,1.19 and 1.20 and it is still working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach. This one involves a kubectl plugin, [kubectl-view-secret](https://github.com/elsesiy/kubectl-view-secret), the good part is it doesn't print all the secrets only the selected ones, which might be beneficial from time to time.

This is how it works.

**Setup**

```bash
#suppose you have krew installed
❯ kubectl krew install view-secret
```

**Working Example**

```bash
❯ kubectl get secrets 
NAME                        TYPE                             DATA   AGE
cert-manager-webhook-ca     Opaque                           3      30d
harbor-global-docker-pull   kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson   1      30d

❯ kubectl view-secret cert-manager-webhook-ca
Multiple sub keys found. Specify another argument, one of:
-> ca.crt
-> tls.crt
-> tls.key

❯ kubectl view-secret cert-manager-webhook-ca ca.crt
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIBwj.......
```

Answer (score 2):

```bash
$kubectl get secret grafana -n monitoring -o jsonpath='{.data}'
```

The output is the encoded string

Use the String in the echo command below

```bash
$echo "string" | base64 --decode
```

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes 1.11+

```
kubectl get secrets/db-user-pass --template='{{.data.password | base64decode }}'
```

Answer (score 1):

This one liner is used to get an encoded kubeconfig file from a secret, and generate a file from it to be used dynamically on a ci job for example:

```
kubectl get secret YOUR_SECRET -o json | grep -oP '(?<=\"YOUR_SECRET_KEY\": \")[^\"]*' | base64 --decode > ./YOUR_KUBECONFIG_FILE_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Minimal nodejs CLI tool ([github](https://github.com/boo1ean/kusd))

```
npm i -g kusd
kubectl get secret your-secret -o yaml | kusd
```

Comment: Nice tool. Made my life so much easier!

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Břetislav Hájek solution (thank you very much for that).
If you need to get it by a label, then you'll need to add an extra `range` command to iterate over the returned items.

```sh
$ LABEL_FILTER="app.kubernetes.io/name=mysql-chart"

$ kubectl get secret  -l "$LABEL_FILTER"  -o go-template='
{{range $i := .items}}{{range $k,$v := $i.data}}{{printf "%s: " $k}}{{if not $v}}{{$v}}{{else}}{{$v | base64decode}}{{end}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}'

mysql_password: ...
mysql_root_password: ...
mysql_user: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

With bash. This is running ubuntu 18.04, and Kubernetes 1.18.5

```
kubectl -n metallb-system get secrets memberlist -o json | grep secretkey | grep -v f:s | awk -F '"' '{print$4}' |base64 --decode; echo
```

Answer (score 0):

This would help if you have yaml file for k8s secrets.
You can use this intellij plugin to decode all base64 encoded values in a yaml file.
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19099-yaml-base64-decoder

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the secret only offline (for whatever reasons) you can also use yq and jus decode the values back and forth here is an alias snippet:

```
elif [[ ($1 == "secret") && ($2 == "decode") ]]; then
  yq -i '.data[] |= @base64d' $3
elif [[ ($1 == "secret") && ($2 == "encode") ]]; then
  yq -i '.data[] |= @base64' $3
```

$3 is the path to the secret in question.