# How to handle secrets in ConfigMaps?

Tags: kubernetes, configmap, kubernetes-secrets

I would like to use a `Secret` inside a `ConfigMap`. Is this possible?

**Example:**

An example where this might be required is if you would like to write from [Fluentd to S3](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/s3). In the configuration you have to add your AWS credentials.

**Alternatives:**

Using **environment variables** on the cluster itself. I do not like this idea, because the variable would still contain the secret as plain text.

Passing the password during set-up. If you are using **deployment tools** it might be possible to pass the secret during the deployment of your application. This is also not a nice solution since you are still passing the secret as plain text to the deployment tool. An advantage of this approach is that you do not accidentally check-in your secret to git.

Comment: Have you gone through this https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-configmaps-and-secrets-68d061f7ab5b

Comment: Thanks @mchawre. I will have a look at that

Comment: So how I understand it, @mchawre solution works as follows: Pass the secret data to a K8s secret, expose this data via env variables and then consume it in the configmap. Is that correct? Not sure if that might work. In the example he is not passing any secret data to the configmap

Comment: Yeah but that env will contain base 64 encoded data in it. You need to decode it to use.

Comment: The best option so far I think is to use AWS IAM role and assign that role to the kubernetes nodes.

Comment: As you can see `aws_key_id` and `aws_sec_key` are the optional field https://docs.fluentd.org/output/s3#parameters You can make use of aws iam role. Just give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Try to [avoid](https://medium.com/merapar/securing-iam-access-in-kubernetes-cfbcc6954de) making use of aws credentials in kubernetes.

As you can [see](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/s3#parameters) `aws_key_id` and `aws_sec_key` are the optional fields.

Make use of [AWS IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) and assign it to the kubernetes nodes.

And then try to run your fluentd application without aws credentials in its [config](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/s3#example-configuration).

Just give it a try.

Hope this helps.

**Update:**

[This](https://medium.com/merapar/securing-iam-access-in-kubernetes-cfbcc6954de) article explain different ways to use aws iam for kubernetes.

[Kube2iam](https://github.com/jtblin/kube2iam) and many [other](https://medium.com/building-ibotta/moving-from-kube2iam-to-kiam-a000639b839e) tools like this, might help. Give it a try.

Comment: I think this is only possible if you are running on an AWS EC2 instance. See https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-s3

Comment: Yes. where exactly your kubernetes is running on. which cloud provider?

Comment: It should be independent of cloud providers.

Comment: Please go through this https://medium.com/merapar/securing-iam-access-in-kubernetes-cfbcc6954de things will get cleared.

Comment: This looks promising. It works independently of the underlying IaaS provider, right?

Comment: Give it a try. I haven't used this, so can't really comment. Do let me know once you're done.

Comment: I will. Please edit your answer to include the article. Also please include https://github.com/jtblin/kube2iam. I will close the question then

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. You should always use [secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#create-a-secret) for your sensitive data.

By default, secrets are only base64 encoded content of files so you should use something like [Vault](https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/identity-access-management/vault-agent-k8s) to secure store you sensitive data.

Comment: Okay. How would you solve the **example** situation then?

Comment: Exactly like in the [article](https://gist.github.com/thesandlord/6e297d7ceb807e6f0243255ab7885d83#file-final-yaml-L25) mentioned by @mchawre, but like I point, your that is only base64 encoded.

Comment: TL;DR; you will end up with base64 encoded AWS credentials stored in ENV.

Comment: Just note that if you want a more GitOps approach, there are pretty good tools for encrypting secrets - so you can store them on Git. I posted about it in the past - check it out [here](https://blog.solutotlv.com/can-kubernetes-keep-a-secret/)

Comment: @FL3SH The article does not mention a valid solution to my problem. It talks about environment vars, Docker vars and K8s vars. I do not want to store this sensitive data as a clear text war and since it is consumed by a configmap I cannot store it in a secret

Comment: @FL3SH How would you consume the base64 encoded ENVs in a configmap?

Comment: Decoding is pain, these are the available ways https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56909180/decoding-kubernetes-secret