# Kubernetes Dashboard not show admin token

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I installed kubernetes according to this [manual + containerd](https://computingforgeeks.com/deploy-kubernetes-cluster-on-ubuntu-with-kubeadm/), installed the kubernetes dashboard according to [this manual](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-kubernetes-dashboard-with-nodeport/) and created service account for [this manual](https://computingforgeeks.com/create-admin-user-to-access-kubernetes-dashboard/), but when I try to look at the token, the console does not display it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaVgV.jpg)

Comment: looks like you're describing the secret, not getting it. `kubectl get secret <name> -o json | jq '.data | map_values(@base64d)'` ought to decode the values (assuming base64 encoded; also assuming you have `jq`.) You'll need to `-n` the namespace as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decoding Kubernetes secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56909180/decoding-kubernetes-secret)

Comment: `kubectl  get secret SEC-NAME -o go-template='{{.data | base64decode}}'`, no other tool is needed, plain kubectl  using go-template. You may need to update stuff between the curlys.

Comment: Also, in kubernetes.io 1.24 secret is not created automatically for a service account. Consider checking your kubernetes version.

Comment: version v1.24.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### kubernetes: 1.24.0

#### dashboard: 2.6.0

Manually create a service account API token.

https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md