# Kubectl --template returns unknown shorthand flag

Tags: kubectl

I have kubectl configured on my Windows 11 PowerShell command line, it works fine for all commands so far, but when I run the following command [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56909262/5274291):

```bash
kubectl get secrets/my-app -n my-ns --template={{.data.database_host}}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: unknown shorthand flag: 'e' in -encodedCommand
See 'kubectl get --help' for usage.
```

Does anybody know why?

Comment: Does quoting the flag value help: `kubectl get secrets/my-app --namespace=my-new --template="{{.data.database_host}}"`?

Comment: As you are getting an error: unknown shorthand flag: 'e' in -encodedCommand, this might be due to not using encoded in the base64 format.

Try the syntax below. This might work : 

kubectl get secrets/db-user-pass --template='{{.data.password | base64decode}}' .

Refer this [docker for secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#docker-config-secrets)

Comment: Yes, thanks guy the quoting worked, using either `"` or `'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are getting an error: unknown shorthand flag: 'e' in -encodedCommand, this might be due to not using encoded in the base64 format. Try the syntax below. This might work : kubectl get secrets/db-user-pass --template='{{.data.password | base64decode}}' . Refer this [docker for secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#docker-config-secrets)